# jQuery classe Selector multiple elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello I simply wanna highlight the fist element....

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
     var $element = $(".intro");
     $element[0].css("bbroswerackground-color", "yellow");
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Welcome to My Homepage</h1>

<p class="intro">This paragraph has class "intro".</p>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<p class="intro">This paragraph has class "intro".</p>
<p>This is another paragraph.</p>
<p class="intro">This paragraph has class "intro".</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: When you use a subscript on a jQuery object, it returns the DOM element. You have to use `.eq()`, not `[]` to pick out a jQuery object from the collection.

Comment: You should also use `background-color` instead of what you have now:`bbroswerackground-color`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should works :

```
$(".intro").eq(0).css("background-color", "yellow");
```

EDIT : you have an error in background syntax.

EDIT 2 : please next time search by yourself

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to apply/set certain property on the 1st element.

Using `.first()` filter

```
 $(".intro").first().css("background-color", "yellow");
```

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/4y80has5/

Using `:first` selector :

```
 $(".intro:first").css("background-color", "yellow");
```

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/4y80has5/1/

Answer (score 0):

You may also do this without JQuery using CSS3 selector like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
    p.intro:first-of-type {
        color:red;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Welcome to My Homepage</h1>

<p class="intro">This paragraph has class "intro".</p>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<p class="intro">This paragraph has class "intro".</p>
<p>This is another paragraph.</p>
<p class="intro">This paragraph has class "intro".</p>

</body>
</html>
```